# Removing Instances and SQL Server Express edition and going to Standard/Developer/Enterprise

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, sql-server-express

I would like to move from SQL Server 2008 R2 Express to SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer or Enterprise.

I just noticed that I have the following services running:

- SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)
- SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)
- SQL Server (SQLR1)
- SQL Server (SQLR1V2)
- SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)
- SQL Server Agent (SQLR1)
- SQL Server Agent (SQLR1V2)

What I would like to accomplish here is to maintain the databases I have in (local). How can I tell which instance this is running against?

Also, have the Express Edition completely removed and install either the Developer / Enterprise edition of SQL Server with the Management Studio interface. I ultimately want to have SQL Profiler at the end of the day.

I don't mind if I have to remove everything services, instances, management studios, etc.

As long as I can end up with 3 things:

- SQL Server Developer / Enterprise
- SQL Server Management Studio
- SQL Profiler

**Edit:**
I have downloaded SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer (x86, x64, ia64) - DVD (English) from MSDN. However, according to the installation I already have Management Tools - Basic installed.
[image]

**Edit2:**
I actually created a new instance and I was given additional the 2 Management Tools options in the installation, as mentioned by mrdenny.

Comment: Have you already installed DEv/Ent edition to give SQLr1 and SQLR1V2? Or do you have 3 Express edition installs?

Comment: I'm fairly sure there's 3 express editions. I had a disk with Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Standard on it. I tried to install that today (selected every installation option and the MSSQLSERVER instance). I still seem to have no profiler from what I can tell. I'm downloading SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer (x86, x64, ia64) - DVD (English) from MSDN currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Local) without an instance name is the instance named MSSQLSERVER (the "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)" service).

If your only goal here is to get SSMS and SQL Profiler from the normal edition and not the express edition of SSMS that's easy, just install the tools from the Developer edition DVD / ISO.

Launch the installer, get through to the list of services.  Select only the management studio options (there are two, one under the other) and finish the wizard.  This will give you the tools and leave your instances alone.

Comment: Just in the middle of downloading SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer (x86, x64, ia64) - DVD (English) from MSDN. Once I go through the steps you provided, is there a way to remove the other instances? I'll keep you updated when it's done :)

Comment: Yep, go into add remove programs and you'll see a tone of stuff listed in there.  Ignore everything except for the one which says "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2" (or what ever version you are using).  Select that, click Uninstall/Change.  Run through the wizard.  About 1/2 way through it'll ask you what instance you want to remove.

Comment: It's a momentous occasion, I can finally see how slow my DB and queries are running :) Thanks for the help mrdenny.

Comment: No problem. Now for the real work, getting the queries running faster. :)